# C# Usage of Redundant Code Contract-Preconditions

Tags: c#, .net, code-contracts

I did not find the info by reading the usage guidelines, so I ask my question here:
Assuming the following situation:

```
    /// <summary>
    /// Initalisiert eine neue Instanz des SettingsManager
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="settingsRepo">Das SettingsRepository welches die Einstellungen enthält</param>
    public SettingsManager(ISettingsRepository settingsRepo)
    {
        Contract.Requires<ArgumentNullException>(settingsRepo != null, "The parameter settingsRepo cant be null");

        _settingsRepo = settingsRepo;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Lädt alle Einstellungen
    /// </summary>
    public void Load()
    {
        Contract.Requires<NullReferenceException>(_settingsRepo != null, "The repository cant be null");
        .
        .
        .
    }
```

where `_settingsRepo` is a global private field of the class `SettingsManager`. In the constructor, I define the **precondition**, that the parameter `settingsRepo` is not null. So when `settingsRepo` equals `null` an Exception is thrown. But the method `Load()` uses the field `_settingsRepo` which definetly wasn't `null` **during instantiation**. However, I do not know if `_settingsRepo` equals `null` at the moment, when `Load()` is being used, so is the precondition I defined in the method `Load()` considered as redundant, or should I rest this.

Comment: `Load` is an instance method. If `settingsRepo` is null you throw an exception in the C'tor, therefore the object wasn't created. You can remove the validation in `Load`

Comment: Is `_settingsRepo` declared as `readonly`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I mention in the question's comment. You can remove the validation from `Load` method.
The pattern you are using called [`Constructor Injection`](http://misko.hevery.com/2009/02/19/constructor-injection-vs-setter-injection/). The idea behind C'tor injection is the object you are trying to create needs a dependency and don't have any default/alternative behaviour if you don't supply the dependency. In your case it seem exactly the situation.

**Summery:** You verified the `_settingsRepo` is not null in the C'tor, therefore you don't need to verify it again in the `Load'` method.

[This](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1935182501) is a very good book about [DI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependency_injection), I recommends you to read it.

Answer (score 0):

Although you dont have a parameter passed to the method it worth to mention that the general rule is to validate arguments of public methods.

> All reference arguments that are passed to externally visible methods should be checked against null. If appropriate, throw a ArgumentNullException when the argument is null.
>
> If a method can be called from an unknown assembly because it is declared public or protected, you should validate all parameters of the method. If the method is designed to be called only by known assemblies, you should make the method internal and apply the InternalsVisibleToAttribute attribute to the assembly that contains the method.

This goes under the Code analysis : **CA1062: Validate arguments of public methods**

But since you have already validated `_settingsRepo` in a different place that is essential for the `Load` function to be exist, then you could omit the validation. But this might trigger a warning upon release, my suggestion is to run Code analysis prior to releasing the code

[Read more](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms182182.aspx)